# recover pip soft link

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, symlink

My system is Ubuntu 14.04. I installed python 3.5.2 and used the command:

`$ln -s /usr/local/python3.5.2/bin/pip/usr/bin/pip`

to change the Soft Link of pip. But now, I use python 2.7 (System of binding) again. And my pip version is still python3.5.2.

[image: Screenshot.]

What should I do to change the default pip link?

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal,

```
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/local/bin/pip
```

ready !